# jquery, trigger a link click with another click problem?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

i have this situation. I am using a simple tab menu from [here](http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/simple-tabs-w-css-jquery/).

```
<ul class="tabs">
<li><a href="#tab1">tab1</a></li>
<li><a  id="myprofile" href="#tab2">tab2</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
text    
</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
text    
</div>
```

so far so good.

What i want to do is to trigger `#myprofile` from another link:

```
<a id="my_profile" href="" title="My Profile">My Profile</a>
```

I am trying to use something like this:

```
$('#my_profile').click(function() {
// $('#myprofile').click(); // this works
$('#myprofile').trigger('click'); // this works also
});
```

What happens is that when i click on the new link `#my_profile`, i go to the second tab for like 2 seconds then i get redirected to the first tab. But if i click on the tabs it works just fine.

if i use jsfiddle i get a `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` error: see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/fcj4f/), but not on my page.

any ideas?

thanks

Comment: do u want like dis <a id="my_profile" href="#" title="My Profile">My Profile</a>

Comment: success, i tried everything but that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this once

```
<a id="my_profile" href="#" title="My Profile">My Profile</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jquery tabs. Just try this,

```
$('#my_profile').click(function() {
   $(tabContainerSelector).tabs( "option", "selected", 1 );
});
```

See [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#option-selected).